# Python - Appending to a dictionary object is not working as expected

Tags: python, dictionary

I may not be referencing things properly so please bear with me.

I obtain a list of users from an API. The resulting object I have is a dictionary (confirmed with print(type)).

The dictionary has the following:

> {'data': [{'username': 'user1', 'name': {'firstName': 'firstname1',
> 'lastName': 'lastname1'}, 'suspended': False, 'suspendedAt': None},
> {'username': 'user2', 'name': {'firstName': 'firstname2', 'lastName':
> 'lastname2'}, 'suspended': False, 'suspendedAt': None}}]}

I need to add some entries to this dictionary, so I have compiled the following:

```
def whitelist_user_list(userlist):
    #   Add the admin accounts.
    for user in vars.admin_whitelist:
        user_dict = {'username': user, 'name': {'firstName': user, 'lastName': user}, 'suspended': False, 'suspendedAt': None}
        user_dict = dict(user_dict)
        userlist.update(user_dict)
    return userlist
```

The code works, but, the entry I'm adding is added in an odd way, in that it's outside of the closing curly and square brackets and just added to the end as if it's not a part of the dictionary.

> {'data': [{'username': 'user1', 'name': {'firstName': 'firstname1',
> 'lastName': 'lastname1'}, 'suspended': False, 'suspendedAt': None},
> {'username': 'user2', 'name': {'firstName': 'firstname2', 'lastName':
> 'lastname2'}, 'suspended': False, 'suspendedAt': None}**}], 'username':
> 'admin', 'name': {'firstName': 'admin', 'lastName': 'admin'},
> 'suspended': False, 'suspendedAt': None}**

I've followed many different examples of how to add to an existing dictionary and some just outright fail, this is the only one that actually completes. The difficulty being I don't quite know exactly what search term to use and every example I've come across uses much simpler dictionaries as examples.

Please advise how to I properly add these entries to my dictionary?

Comment: Maybe a st*pid question but, `userlist` is a list?

Comment: Please provide a  [minimal reproduciable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your code is now working since `user` is an undefined variable and the indents are causing an error.

Comment: <class 'dict'> is returned when I print(type(userlist)) in my function

Comment: Thank you for your question @Dan. Note that there is an additional curly bracket `}` that should not be there, before the square bracket at the end in the original dictionary.

Comment: It's there as part of the original data -- { data: [{ .... }] }. The problem is that my appended data is being added after the closing square and curly bracket. I'm not adding those in, that's what I'm getting back from the API.

Comment: In the original dictionary, there is one key, `data`. Everything else is the value to that key. Assuming you're passing in the original dictionary as `userlist`, when you call `userlist.update(user_dict)` you are adding 4 additional keys, namely the ones in `user_dict`.

Comment: In your post it's currently `{ data: [{ .... }}] }`

Comment: The supposed output does not match the code shown. The code applies the same value to each of 'username', 'firstName' and 'lastName'. In the output shown we see, for example, 'user1', 'firstname1' and 'lastname1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that *userlist* is initialised thus:

```
userlist = {'data': []}
```

i.e., the dictionary has a single key ('data') with a list as its associated value.

Which means that you could do this:

```
def whitelist_user_list(userlist):
    #   Add the admin accounts.
    for user in vars.admin_whitelist:
        user_dict = {'username': user, 'name': {'firstName': user, 'lastName': user}, 'suspended': False, 'suspendedAt': None}
        userlist['data'].append(user_dict)
    return userlist
```

Comment: Thanks for answering with an answer instead of a comment. Comments make it much more difficult to format properly. Your answer has in fact perfectly dealt with the issue - the absence of referencing the key[data] was the issue. I can confirm the entire array of admin accounts has now been added to my dictionary. Thanks again.